# Are all trees in Fibonacci heaps binomial trees?

Tags: data-structures, tree, heap, fibonacci-heap

Is it possible for a Fibonacci heap to contain a tree that isn't a binomial tree?  If so, how would this happen?  Can you give an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this can happen.  Intuitively, the reason is that in a Fibonacci heap, the decrease-key operation can work by cutting a subtree from a larger tree, resulting in two trees that are (potentially) not binomial trees.  This differs from the binomial heap, where decrease-key works by doing a bubble-up operation from the node whose key was decreased all the way up to the root.

To see a concrete example, let's insert five elements into a Fibonacci heap, say, 1, 3, 5, 7, and 9.  This gives the heap

```
1 - 3 - 5 - 7 - 9
```

Now, let's do a dequeue-min, which extracts 1.  We now try to compact all of the remaining elements together, which merges the trees as follows:

```
    3
   /|
  5 7
    |
    9
```

Now, suppose that we do a decrease-key operation on to decrease the key of 9 to 6.  To do this, we cut 9 from its parent and merge it into the list of trees at the top, which yields

```
   3 - 6
  /|
 5 7
```

And now the tree with 3 at its root contains only 3 elements, so it is not a binomial tree anymore.

Hope this helps!